# How to enable HTTP/2 support in CloudFront using serverless?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, http2, serverless-framework

How to enable HTTP/2 support in CloudFront using serverless?

I am using serverless (https://github.com/serverless/serverless) to create a simple serverless application that serves HTML + JS from S3 container using CloudFront.

To this end, I am writing a serverless.yml template that will afterwards build this setup for me.

What do I need to include/configure in the template in order to enable HTTP/2 support in CloudFront?

Comment: AWS now supports HTTP/3. I posted a new answer in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding **HttpVersion: 'http2'** below **DistributionConfig:** property. See full example below.

```
## Specifying the CloudFront Distribution to server your Web Application
WebAppCloudFrontDistribution:
  Type:                               AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
  Properties:
    DistributionConfig:
      HttpVersion:                    'http2'
      Origins:
        - DomainName:                 ${self:custom.s3Bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com
          ## An identifier for the origin which must be unique within the distribution
          Id:                         WebApp
          CustomOriginConfig:
            HTTPPort:                 80
            HTTPSPort:                443
            OriginProtocolPolicy:     https-only
          ## In case you want to restrict the bucket access use S3OriginConfig and remove CustomOriginConfig
          # S3OriginConfig:
          #   OriginAccessIdentity:   origin-access-identity/cloudfront/E127EXAMPLE51Z
      Enabled:                        'true'
      ## Uncomment the following section in case you are using a custom domain
      # Aliases:
      # - mysite.example.com
      DefaultRootObject:              index.html
      ## Since the Single Page App is taking care of the routing we need to make sure ever path is served with index.html
      ## The only exception are files that actually exist e.h. app.js, reset.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP asked for HTTP/2 support, [AWS announced HTTP/3 support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-http-3-support-for-amazon-cloudfront/) for CloudFront in **August 2022**.

So in addition to enabling HTTP/2 support ([see Cninroh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855776/2419808)), you can also enable HTTP/3, as suggested in the [AWS official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-distributionconfig.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-distributionconfig-httpversion):

> Allowed values: http1.1 | http2 | http2and3 | http3

HTTP/3:

```
HttpVersion: 'http3'
```

HTTP/2 and HTTP/3:

```
HttpVersion: 'http2and3'
```